# enable display-manager after disabling

Tags: lubuntu, display-manager

I mistakenly ran

`sudo systemctl disable display-manager`

and I now want to re-enable it, However when I run

`sudo systemctl enable display-manager`

I get the error

`Failed to enable unit: Unit file display-manager.service does not exist.`

How do I enable the display-manager again?

Comment: You've not provided release details; but my Lubuntu system responds "*Unit display-mananger.service could not be found.*" so the error is expected for your *unstated* release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm`

should cause it to to be reconfigured and restart correctly.

You didn't provide release details; but it works on the release I tested it with.

Comment: Thanks - That worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Just do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` replace gdm3 with lightdm or any display manager you've installed or using currently.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` will only give errors on currently supported release of Ubuntu; firstly Lubuntu doesn't provide `gdm`, but even Ubuntu Desktop uses `gdm3` as GNOME 3 has been used for many releases now.

Comment: Yes, so please replace gdm with whatever manager you are currently using

Comment: Given Lubuntu doesn't use it (*and never has*); the OP may not know what DM they're actually using; providing the commands that allow them to work that out may help if you don't want to look up the details yourself.